# How to fail my Bash script if the current directory doesn't exist?

Tags: bash

How can I detect in a Bash script if the current directory DOESN'T exist, and fail cleanly with a message like "Your current directory doesn't exist!" ?

So how can I write a script that would work in the following example?

```
$ mkdir /tmp/wow
$ cd /tmp/wow
$ pwd
/tmp/wow
$ rm -fr /tmp/wow
$ my_script.sh
Your current directory doesn't exist!
```

Comment: Caveat: If you need to handle *renames*, then you've got a problem. Being in the directory, in and of itself, adds to its reference count, and so means that it isn't truly deleted, even if it isn't unreachable from any parent.

Comment: I assume `my_script.sh` actually lives somewhere *other* than `/tmp/wow`?

Comment: @chepner - yeah it lives in my `~/bin/` folder...

Comment: Actually -- there *is* a better answer, but it's platform-specific. Can we go Linux-only here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Nonportable Answer

(This depends on standard UNIX filesystem implementation details -- nothing too scary or nonportable there -- but also on the specific implementation of the `stat(2)` family of syscalls for your filesystem; thus, here there be dragons).

Every inode, including that of directories, retains a "link count" -- the number of references to it. For files, this represents the number of hardlinks; for directories, the link from the parent is 1, the `.` directory is another, and `..` from any subdirectory adds a third or later. (If a directory is `/`, of course, there is no link from a parent).

With a filesystem properly using this accounting, the stat data will reflect the number of links. Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
link_count=$(stat --format=%h .)    ## --format=%h requires GNU stat
if (( link_count == 0 )); then      ## 0 works w/ ext* on Linux, not guaranteed elsewhere
  echo "This directory has been deleted! Voluntarily exiting" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

*However*, not all operating systems correctly expose this accounting. For a HFS filesystem on MacOS, for instance, a directory will not display a link count less than 2 even if it is unlinked from its parents (and thus only existing by virtue of reference-counting in memory -- as discussed below).

---

## Portable Answer

#### Short form

While it is possible for your current directory to *be unlinked* (that is, to have no link to it from a parent directory that can be used to traverse to it from the filesystem root), it is impossible for your current directory to *not exist*. Being your current directory *forces* a directory to continue to exist, by virtue of keeping its in-memory reference count above zero, even if there exists no parent directory which has it as a subdirectory.

#### Long form (and buggy, broken workaround)

If you're willing to have false-positives when a directory has been *moved*:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -d "$PWD" ] || { echo "Your current directory doesn't exist!" >&2; exit 1; }
```

That said, this doesn't detect the case when a new and different directory has been created where your old one used to be. To handle that, we might add some additional logic, like the following:

```
# perl isn't *truly* portable, in the POSIX-specified sense, but it's everywhere.
ino() { perl -e '@s=stat($ARGV[0]); printf("%s %s\n", $s[0], $s[1]);' "$@"; }
cur_ino=$(ino .)
pwd_ino=$(ino "$PWD")
if [ "$cur_ino" != "$pwd_ino" ]; then
  echo "Directory has been replaced! Following..." >&2
  cd "$PWD" || exit
fi
```

However, like any other file, having an open handle on a directory will prevent it from being *deleted* as such. Thus, `rm -rf /tmp/wow` in your example isn't really deleting the directory, *until your shell (and any other software) is no longer in it*, because until that happens, its in-memory reference count isn't 0.

Consequently, when `[ -d . ]` tells you that your directory still exists, even though it's been deleted... that's actually true! Your directory *does* still exist, because the fact that your shell is currently in it forces it to continue to exist.

Comment: hey! thanks for the ideas! I've tried this and keep getting fails though. This is what I get when I try and run what you've suggested  `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Your current directory doesn't exist!`

Comment: Yup -- those messages are generated during setup before your script is actually started, so there's not much you can do about them.

Comment: @BradParks, ...that said, other than the final `Your current directory doesn't exist!`, those messages are just warnings on stderr -- they don't actually modify behavior or script output (in the formal sense of "content written to stdout"). The exit status is the one given by the `exit` in my command. If you try modifying the `exit 1` to be, say, `exit 5` and check `$?` after running the script, you'll observe that to be the case.

Comment: Hmmm... i get ya.... if I just edit my script down to just `echo hi`, that works, but as soon as I try and use `$PWD` or `pwd` in the script, it dies like above. If there were a tricky way to find the PWD then I might be able to do a different check on it...

Comment: Again, it "dies like above" because the code I gave you *makes* it die, because that's what I thought you wanted. `echo $PWD` on its own throws some warnings to stderr, but it still prints the working directory as it last existed, and it doesn't cause any kind of death.

Comment: ...at risk of repeating myself: That it's the code I gave you making it die, and not anything related to the internal warnings the shell is emitting is something you can prove by changing the exit status in the `exit 1`, and seeing that `$?` reflects that changed exit status.

Comment: Awesome... thanks for the help and info... much appreciated!

Comment: For the nonportable solution, is there a way to get rid of the false *negatives* if `$PWD` exists but isn’t the directory I’m in? This can happen when something else has run `rm -rf /tmp/wow; mkdir /tmp/wow`.

Comment: The nonportable solution shouldn't have that bug, as it doesn't refer to `$PWD` -- only the portable solution does. That said, by comparing `stat` data, yes, we could make that happen.

Comment: ...the tricky thing there is extracting stat data (ie. inode number) portably; `stat --format` is a GNUism (though BSD has something similar, its usage isn't quite identical).

Comment: @DanielH, ...if you can provide a reproducer for the bug in question using the nonportable approach (`stat --format=%h .`), could you report the filesystem you're using? I'm curious now -- and could see that happening on vfat or some network filesystems, but would be surprised if it were happening somewhere modern design were in play.

Comment: @DanielH, ...in the interim, I've added a mechanism for detecting directory replacement to the portable version.

Comment: Using `pwd; ls -al; rmdir $PWD; mkdir $PWD; ls -al; [ -d "$PWD" ]; echo $?` in an empty directory, the last line is always zero on NFS, tmpfs, and ext4. Various other details (like the `total` line in the first `ls` and whether `pwd` returns a path or gives an error) are different on the different file systems. The second `ls` always says `total 0` and gives no other output; the first `ls` says `total 0` on tmpfs but also lists `.` and `..`. It seems like `ls -al | wc -l` being 1 works, at least on Linux, on all filesystems I tested.

Comment: @DanielH, `[ -d "$PWD" ]` is not used in the nonportable version at all.

Comment: @DanielH, ...and unfortunately, `ls -al | wc -l` does not work correctly on HFS on MacOS (even unlinked directories show both `.` and `..`), so we're still nonportable there.

Comment: Oops, I meant to type “portable”. The nonportable solution will probably work for me. Sorry for the confusion! Edit: yeah, it did

Answer (score 2):

Typically one tests if a directory (*any* directory, including the current working one) exists only to facilitate either:

1. Creating a missing directory (`mkdir -p`)
2. Storing files (`mktemp`, `touch`, etc.)

It is this last case that can, perhaps, be used to detect if your current working directory (`.`) is available:

```
function cwd_exists() {
    local fn
    local rc
    fn=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp 2>/dev/null)
    rc=$?
    [ -e "$fn" ] && rm -f "$fn"
    return $rc;
}
```

Inserting into a demo script:

```
home=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$home"
cwd_exists && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Gone'
mv "$home" "$home.backup"
cwd_exists && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Gone'
mv "$home.backup" "$home"
cwd_exists && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Gone'
rm -rf "$home"
cwd_exists && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Gone'
mkdir "$home"
cwd_exists && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Gone'
```

Will echo what I think is the desired behavior:

```
Exists
Exists
Exists
Gone
Gone
```

Even though the directory exists (by virtue of your script holding it open), the directory doesn't exist when `mktemp` tries to write into it, even if another process comes along and gives the same path name (because the inodes are different).

Comment: Ahh -- as-edited, this is no longer prone to the issue (your `mv "$home" "$home.backup"` case covers it).

Comment: (There's a caveat here in that "existing but non-writable" can be conflated with "non-existing", but there are plenty of use cases where that caveat isn't a pertinent one).

Comment: BTW, `mktemp -p .` isn't valid usage on MacOS. Using GNU mktemp there, however, everything works as intended -- so the rule that new content can't be created in unlinked directories holds.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, I *thought* you might mean the `$PWD` issue, which I addressed with my edit. Sleep helps. Also, thanks for the MacOS tip: I fixed that to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether current dir is deleted, try following:

```sh
# First get the inode number of current dir, e.g. 117002
ls -ial | grep '\s\.$' | awk '{print $1}'

# Then try to find the inode's path in parent dir. If none, then the original dir was deleted
find .. -inum 117002
```